# Data structure to store number of open files in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand the Linux data structures and the way it manages open files. As per my understanding, each `task_struct` points to `files_struct`, which holds the list of all open file descriptors. Each such entry is a pointer to `struct file`. This structure has all the information needed to operate on any particular file.

Does `f_count` member of `struct file` indicates the number of open instances of the same file ? If so, does kernel create one `file struct` for every opened file instance ?

Example : /users/soverflow/test.txt
If processes P1, P1 and P3 opens the same file "/users/soverflow/test.txt", does kernel create "three" `file struct` corresponding to P1, P2 and P3 or does it create only one `file struct` and all the processes points to the same structure ?

If all the processes points to the same structure, how do they know current file position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` structure tracks a single instance of an opened file. In the scenario you describe, each process will get its own copy of the structure. The `f_count` member of the structure is used to track multiple file *descriptors* referring to the same instance of the file. And `f_pos` is used to track the current file position for each instance.

`f_count` can be incremented by `dup(2)` as well as by `fork(2)`. `dup` creates another unique file descriptor which refers to exactly the same open file instance. Likewise, when your process calls `fork`, the parent and child processes both have references to the same file instances. Multiple file descriptors that reference the same struct `file` share the file position it tracks.

Example:
If your process calls `open(2)` on the same file twice, it will get two file descriptors each referring to a separate instance of struct `file` (each with `f_count` set to 1). But if it calls `open` once, then calls `dup` with the returned file descriptor, it will still have two file descriptors but each now refers to the same single struct `file` with `f_count` set to 2.